# Send message key inside the EventActivityBinder.Produce method

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, masstransit

I'm working on a project using Masstransit with Sagas and Kafka and just stumble upon an issue. I'm trying to use the  `EventActivityBinder.Produce` to produce messages to some Kafka topic. The problem is that the defined producer needs a message key to be specified and I couldn't figure out a way to send the message key using this `EventActivityBinder.Produce` method so it raises an exception saying that the producer is not registered.

So, my question is: **is it possible to send a message key using this `produce` method mentioned above?**

Here is the method that I`ve implemented:

```
public static EventActivityBinder<OrderRequestSagaInstance, ErrorMessageEvent> NotifySourceSystem(
    this EventActivityBinder<OrderRequestSagaInstance, ErrorMessageEvent> binder)
{
    var @event = binder.Produce(context =>
    {
        context.Saga.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;

        var @event = new
        {
            Success = false,
            context.Saga.Reason,
            __Header_Reason = context.Saga.Reason,
        };

        return context.Init<ResponseWrapper<OrderResponseEvent>>(@event);
    });

    return @event;
}
```

and there's my producer registration

```
rider.AddProducer<string, ResponseWrapper<OrderResponseEvent>>(kafkaTopics.SourceSystemTopic);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this `BehaviorContext.GetServiceOrCreateInstance` method, passing the registration signature of my producer. Apparently, it worked but I'm absolutely not confident that that is the best approach. I do believe that, ideally, the `EventActivityBinder.Produce` method should have an option in which we could pass the key, if necessary! But anyways, here goes the code.

```
public static EventActivityBinder<OrderRequestSagaInstance, ErrorMessageEvent> NotifySourceSystem(
    this EventActivityBinder<OrderRequestSagaInstance, ErrorMessageEvent> binder)
{
    Func<BehaviorContext<OrderRequestSagaInstance>, Task> asyncAction = async context =>
    {        
        await context.GetServiceOrCreateInstance<ITopicProducer<string, ErrorMessageEvent>()
            .Produce(
                Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                context.Saga.NotificationReply!,
                context.CancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    };
    
    return binder.Add(new AsyncActivity<OrderRequestSagaInstance>(asyncAction));
}
```